# null, org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. on Firefox

Tags: selenium, webdriver

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Firefox Version: 45 esr
Selenium: 2.53

I am getting this error, sometimes all tests passing successfully sometimes this error is encountering.

All tests was passing successfully with

Firefox Version: 38 esr
Selenium: 2.46

After upgrade this issue came, is this compatibility issue or driver is crashing

Comment: Pl reformat your question summary/description, and paste the code causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are able to do the following, but my advice is to downgrade to Firefox 38esr. I have tried with the same tests (big test suites) the following setups:

- Selenium 2.53.1 with Firefox 38.6.1esr -> it works fine.
- Selenium 2.53.1 with Firefox 45.2.0esr -> browser randomly dies.

The problem seems to be generated by Firefox 45esr. I do not know if there is some conflict with Selenium 2.53.1. or just Firefox 45esr has some bug that induces the browser to die.

I'll tell you my own experience in case it is useful for someone:

This issue is also happening to me since June more or less. I have several test suites and everything was working fine. I was using Firefox 38.6.1esr and Selenium 2.47.1. I updated to Firefox 45.2.0esr and Selenium 2.53.1. After that update some random error started to happen. I have recorded what is going on and the browser just dies randomly. Sometimes it crashes when the browser is being started and other times at the middle of some action. No clear pattern.

### ERROR MESSAGE:

> `Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
>   Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
>   System info: host: 'ubuntu.localdomain', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-106-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_101'
>   Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
>   Session ID: dbed6592-c61c-447a-818a-3fd57c96b860
>   Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, overlappingCheckDisabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=45.0}]
>   Command duration or timeout: 219 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
>   System info: host: 'ubuntu.localdomain', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-106-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_101'
>   Session ID: 454af9e4-fffb-4f95-990f-262a6e5e970c
>   Driver info: com.openbravo.test.integration.selenium.RemoteWebDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, overlappingCheckDisabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=454af9e4-fffb-4f95-990f-262a6e5e970c, version=45.0, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]`

--

By the way, I would like to use FF45esr and Selenium 2.53.1 since it is not a possibility to downgrade to FF38esr but I have not seen a solution yet.